# Setting queue size for seda works for "to" but not for "toD"

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am using jboss fuse/camel 2.11 on spring boot, a seda component with static uri "to" works with queue size setup for seda, here is the sample:

camel-context1.xml:

```
<to id="_toPreProcessor" uri="vm:request-preprocessor?size={{rest.queueSize}}"/>
```

camel-context2.xml:

```
<from id="_preprocessor-from" uri="vm:request-preprocessor"/>
```

But if "to" in first context is changed to "toD" as the following:

```
<toD id="_toPreProcessor" uri="vm:request-preprocessor?size={{rest.queueSize}}"/>
```

There will be the following error happens:

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: vm://request-preprocessor?size=2 due to: Cannot use existing queue vm://request-preprocessor as the existing queue size 2147483647 does not match given queue size 2
```

I wonder why configuring size for seda works with "to" but not with "toD".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it works, but you could try to build the full target uri in an intermediate header, and later use this header as the sole token in the toD uri:

```
<setHeader headerName="myDynamicUri">
  <simple>vm:request-preprocessor?size={{rest.queueSize}}</simple>
</setHeader>
<log message="Dynamic URI: ${header.myDynamicUri}" loggingLevel="DEBUG"/>
<toD uri="${header.myDynamicUri}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been solved by Using fuse7.0.